# Using python regular expression to find an image path

Tags: python, regex

I have a variable like the one below:

```
var = '<img src="path_1"><p>Words</p><img src="path_2>'
```

Its a string, but inside is obviously html elements. How do I get the first path only (i.e. path_1) using a regex?

I am trying something like this:

```
match = re.match(r'src=\"[\w-]+\"', var)
print match.group(0)
```

I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: `match` finds only from beginning..[`If zero or more characters at the beginning of string match the regular expression pattern`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.match)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You [should use an HTML parser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags) like [`BeautifulSoup`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/):

```
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> var = '<img src="path_1"><p>Words</p><img src="path_2>'
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(var, "html.parser")
>>> soup.img["src"]
'path_1'
```

As for the regex-approach, you need to make the following changes to make it work:

- switch to [`re.search()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.search), `re.match()` starts matching from the beginning of the string
- add a *[capturing group](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/regex.html#grouping)* to capture the `src` value
- there is no need to escape double quotes

Fixed version:

```
>>> re.search(r'src="([\w-]+)"', var).group(1)
'path_1'
```

Comment: I would say : You ***should*** use an HTML parser

Comment: @PedroLobito definitely, made changes and referenced the famous thread. Thanks.

Comment: Wow I actually did not even know this existed. This looks like a perfect fit. Thanks a lot!

Comment: One question, how do I get the second path? Since soup.img["src"] only returns the first one.

Comment: @TahmidKhanNafee sure, you can use `find_all()`. E.g. the second image: `soup.find_all("img")[1]["src"]`. Or, all `src` values of all images: `[img["src"] for img in soup.find_all("img")]`.

Answer (score 2):

As suggested in the comments, use `search()` since `match()` will try to match your regular expression from the beginning of the string. You can also use capturing a named group to make the code more readable:

```
var = '<img src="path_1"><p>Words</p><img src="path_2>'
import re
match = re.search(r'src=\"(?P<path1>[\w-]+)\"', var)
if match:
    print(match.group('path1'))
```

Output:

```
path_1
```

Answer (score 1):

Try,

```
path1= re.search(r'<img\s+src="(.*?)"><p>',var).group(1) # path_1
```

1. `BeutifulSoup` is convenient. But *very* slow.
2. `HTMLParser` is a lot faster. But using it is painful.
3. `re` is the *fastest* option and in my opinion, for *stateless* usecases it's worth it.

If the target text is *stateful*, i.e lots of nesting and capturing the semantics is important, instead of implementing a state machine e.g a parser use an available parser. I would strongly suggest **lxml** for parsing HTML and XML. It is a little bit less convenient than `bs4` but comparable to `re` in speed.

Comment: It is too strong of a statement to say `BeautifulSoup` is "very slow". You can configure it to use a different parser under the hood: say `lxml`: `BeautifulSoup(data, "lxml")`. Or you can parse a part of a document via `SoupStrainer` etc.

Comment: I am aware of it. Even if you use `lxml` under the hood, it is slower than `re` by a magnitude. All the object creations and look ups..